# How to call Kdiff3 API in C#

Tags: c#

Does Kdiff3 have APIs available? Or is there any comparison tool's API available that can be used in C#?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: compare 2 files and highlight the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KDiff doesn't seem to have an API which you could make calls to. However there are various [command line commands](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html) you could invoke. I'm not sure about the format of the diff results, but it's possible you could analyse them in code to find any differences between your input files.

CodeProject also has a downloadable [comparison algorithm project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx) which you could attempt to integrate into your solution.

Comment: The command line arguments don't return any data, they are only used to execute kdiff with different options :(